# How to keep icon in unity launcher and remove from desktop?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

A number of applications (e.g. Crashplan) install a desktop icon. This can be moved to also appear in the Unity launcher bar, so now there are two icons. If I delete the desktop one the unity bar one also disappears.

Is there a way to just keep the one in the Unity bar?

Comment: Which "applications" install to the desktop?  Are you talking about Wine applications, and programs that're run in Wine doing this?  Because Linux programs rarely get icons put on the desktop

Comment: For example the Crashplan linux version(https://www.code42.com/crashplan/download/) and also Maple for linux. So no, not WINE apps.

Comment: Why can't you just delete the desktop icon, open the dash and run the app, then right click on it and select "Lock to launcher"?

Comment: copy it to a diffrent folder then drag to launcher, say keep your custom launxhers in Documents folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of drag and drop to the Unity launcher, simply move the icon to `~/.local/share/applications` in which `~` is your home folder.

Create one if any of these folders doesn’t exist.

After moving it to the folder, the icon will appear on Dash and can be locked to the launcher.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention if you wanted all users to see the icon, you should move it to the directory `/usr/share/applications/`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on 16.04 Ubuntu and here is how I remove the desktop Icon and put it into the Launcher:

1. Move Icon to Trash using the Right mouse click menu
2. Open Trash
3. Drag the Associated file for the icon from Trash over to the Launcher and drop it into the launcher.
4. Now you only have an Icon in the Launcher